# How to save an XmlDocument object when you don't know path where it is getting stored?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xpathdocument

I have one `XPathDocument` object. Which I convert to `XmlDocument` object using:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();    
xmldoc.Load(doc.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
```

Now I have updated this `xmldoc` object and trying to save using `Save` method. But it expects a `string` which I don't know.

How should I save my changes to this? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to save `xmldoc`? How will you use it later? Why it is not enough to hold reference to `xmldoc`?

Comment: I am receiving XPathDocument object from another function and have to return same once I am done with my edits in XmlElements. How else can I save changes if not using Save method? Please suggest.

Comment: what is the return type of the function? `List<XmlElement>`?

Comment: Actually it is XpathDocument. It is a static xml file stored in db with some wrong data. My intention is to correct that data. The module which is being used to correct some other data uses xpathdocument object with xslt. But I have to update it without xslt and with help of C# and DOM.

Comment: So the function gets `XpathDocument`, removes some nodes and returns `XpathDocument` with the changes?

Comment: yes, it modify one node and should return xpathdoucment object to execute other modifications using xslt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 XPathDocument result = new XPathDocument((doc.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree()));
```